# Website not running when I shift to another server

Tags: web, server, dns, cpanel

Our website not running on new server [Tour website](https://www.goodshepherdtour.com) we have 2 servers one of them the site working good, we have moved the portal to other server, so when we point the dns it is not working...[Web not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHbH8.png) and then you can see the panel of that server in second image[CWP web control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fadb.png) I need the solution, kindly give the proper solution...

Answer (score 0):

You are using CentOS Web panel as the hosting control panel. While browsing the website check the apache error logs on the server at path

/usr/local/apache/logs/

and those logs will give you idea of whats happening.